# Why are standard library types accessible inside `std` despite being nested in implementation-defined namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, c++20, std

I was browsing the implementation of the `<optional>` header for GCC 11.2 (which can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional;h=449c27a80c46e4d6888bcee098480d53937c5c23;hb=refs/heads/releases/gcc-11)), and I noticed something I'm struggling to understand. Here's the header with (hopefully) only the important bits left out:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_OPTIONAL
#define _GLIBCXX_OPTIONAL 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#if __cplusplus >= 201703L

/* Includes of various internal and library headers */

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

#if __cplusplus == 201703L
# define __cpp_lib_optional 201606L
#else
# define __cpp_lib_optional 202106L
#endif

  /* Implementation */

  template<typename _Tp>
  class optional;

  /* Implementation */

  template<typename _Tp>
  class optional: /* Implementation */
  { /* Implementation */ };

  /* Implementation */


_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
} // namespace std

#endif // C++17

#endif // _GLIBCXX_OPTIONAL
```

I found that `_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION` and `_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION` expand to `namespace __8 {` and `}`, respectively (there's no `inline` before `namespace __8`).

Therefore, it looks like `std::optional` is actually defined inside the non-inline namespace `std::__8`, but despite that, I can obviously reference `std::optional` in my programs as if it was located directly within `std`.

I don't think there are any `using` directives in effect, first because I haven't found any, and second because it should be allowed to specialize `std::optional` for custom types without opening implementation-defined namespaces ([[namespace.std#2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2), [[temp.spec.partial.general#6]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.general#6)).

The `_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)` macro expands to `__attribute__ ((__visibility__ ("default")))`, but I think it's unrelated ([documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)). I couldn't find `system_header` in the list of pragmas in the documentation.

Therefore, I don't understand the reason why I should be able to reference the optional class as `std::optional` and not `std::__8::optional`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Only the first declaration needs the inline specifier https://wandbox.org/permlink/KGbd6EWKRvyhbNLL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `c++config` in libstdc++ that defines these macros also initially declares the version namespace as `inline` [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/f0530882d99abc410bb080051aa04e5cea848f18/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/c%2B%2Bconfig#L348-L370):

```cpp
// Defined if inline namespaces are used for versioning.
#define _GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION 

// Inline namespace for symbol versioning.
#if _GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION
# define _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION namespace __8 {
# define _GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION }

namespace std
{
inline _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION
#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
  inline namespace literals {
    inline namespace chrono_literals { }
    inline namespace complex_literals { }
    inline namespace string_literals { }
#if __cplusplus > 201402L
    inline namespace string_view_literals { }
#endif // C++17
  }
#endif // C++14
_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
}
```

And once a `namespace` is declared `inline`, it's always `inline`. For instance:

```cpp
namespace A {
  inline namespace B {
    struct X { };
  }
}

namespace A {
  namespace B {
    struct Y { };
  }
}

A::X x; // ok
A::Y y; // still ok
```

clang warns on this even if gcc doesn't, but also it's a system header so even if gcc wanred on it it wouldn't matter.

Still, not sure why not just add `inline` to the macro definition. We're probably not at the point where the additional 7 characters per header is a significant detriment to compile time?

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Isn't the file name `c++config` rather than `config.h`?

Comment: Is something like `std::__8::vector` valid in user code? (Regardless of its usefulness.)